# Multiple Layouts in One Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout

I'm making an app with a list of champions, and when user search for a champion then it will open Activity and there i want to have 3 buttons and every one of them will show diffrent Layout and all of this Layouts will have the same 3 buttons for switching between Layouts.
I just want: 1 champion -> 1 Activity -> 3 Layouts ( every Layout has 3 same buttons).

Here is how my Layouts look like for one Champion, i got 3 buttons which are the same in every layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehn0F.jpg

I already tried to use View.GONE/VISIBLE but that doesn't work and this also won't work because when i enter Activity at start Layout is zyra_build and when i click button Story Layout is changed but then buttons don't work.

```java
public class ZyraActivity extends MenuActivity {

    Button buildBtn, storyBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zyra_build);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        buildBtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonShowHideBuild);
        storyBtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonShowHideStory);

        buildBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_zyra_build);
            }
        });

        storyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_zyra_story);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also this 3 buttons will look the same in every Layout for every Champion so: how create them and use in every Layout and how switch between Layouts in one Activity with button Click.

Comment: Use TabLayout with Fragment @1haker

Comment: Thank you ! That's what i was looking for :)